# Dynamic Drop Down List in Excel 365

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've created a spreadsheet that has a drop down menu of names to choose from.

The names are stored in a series of cells on a worksheet.
Each name has a priority number in an adjacent cell.

From those cells, I've created a table with those names sorted into order based in the value of the priority number.

The drop down menu (on another worksheet) then lists the names in the correct priority order.

What I want to do, is when a name is chosen in the drop down list, I want that name to then go to the bottom of the list for the next time the spreadsheet is used.

In my head, I need to make the priority number attached to each name become the highest value after that name is selected.

For example:

Mary 1
Steve 2
David 3
Robert 4

Mary gets selected, so I want the order to then be

Mary 4
Steve 1
David 2
Robert 3

I've played around with various formulae, but can't work out how I can make those numbers change to alter the drop down list order.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll need VBA as I don't think a formula can access dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

## 0. Caveat

This is probably not the most efficient solution. It's 100% formulas without VBA but reversing arrays back and forth in Excel is lengthy so you get this monster formula.

## 1. Setup the initial list of names

This is just a plain text list of names in the order you want them to appear in the drop-down list. If someone has never picked a name in your actual data, this list will ensure they still show up in the drop-down. I did this in a sheet called `Lists`.

## 2. Setup your data sheet

This is where people will pick names from the drop-down. This is probably already setup for you. I made a sheet called `Data`.

## 3. Setup a place for your drop-down list source

I used another column in the lists sheet.

## 4. Enter this monster formula

```
=LET(originalNames,Lists!A2:A5,chosenNames,Data!A2:A20,originalRows,ROWS(originalNames),chosenRows,ROWS(chosenNames),seq,SEQUENCE(originalRows+chosenRows),allNames,IF(seq<=originalRows,INDEX(originalNames,seq),INDEX(chosenNames,seq-originalRows)),reversedNames,INDEX(allNames,SEQUENCE(ROWS(allNames),,ROWS(allNames),-1)),uniqueNames,UNIQUE(FILTER(reversedNames,reversedNames<>0)),INDEX(uniqueNames,SEQUENCE(ROWS(uniqueNames),,ROWS(uniqueNames),-1)))
```

You need to edit the range references as the very beginning but that's it. The `LET()` function allows you to define `variable name, variable value` so you can reference it later. That lets us break down the formula like this:

- `originalNames,Lists!A2:A5` saves the hard-coded list of names you made.
- `chosenNames,Data!A2:A20` saves all the names that people have entered so far. This can reference a field in a table or any other way to reference a single column of data.
- `originalRows,ROWS(originalNames)` counts the rows in the original list. Useful later.
- `chosenRows,ROWS(chosenNames)` counts the rows in the data list. Useful later.
- `seq,SEQUENCE(originalRows+chosenRows)` sets up an array of values from 1 to however many rows we're going to need total.
- `allNames,IF(seq<=originalRows,INDEX(originalNames,seq),INDEX(chosenNames,seq-originalRows))` concatenates the two arrays with the hard-coded list first and then the data list second.
- `reversedNames,INDEX(allNames,SEQUENCE(ROWS(allNames),,ROWS(allNames),-1))` reverses that list.
- `uniqueNames,UNIQUE(FILTER(reversedNames,reversedNames<>0))` filters out all blanks (which are converted to `0` by now) and then extracts just the unique values so that each name only appears once.
- `INDEX(uniqueNames,SEQUENCE(ROWS(uniqueNames),,ROWS(uniqueNames),-1))` reverses the final list and prints it out. The last parameter in `LET()` is not paired with a variable name because it is the output.

What we have now is a list that first has all the names from the hard-coded list that were never chosen (in the order your originally typed them) and then the unique names that have been chosen in the data with the most recent name at the end.

## 5. Define a dynamic named range based this result

My formula was in `Lists!C2` with a header in `C1` so I wrote the formula for my dynamic named range like this:

```
=OFFSET(Lists!$C$2,0,0,COUNTA(Lists!$C:$C)-1)
```

That starts at `C2` and then makes the list taller based on how many values there are in that column (not counting the header at the top, hence the `-1` near the end).

[image: button] [image: manager]

## 6. Define your drop-down list to be based on this named range

I named my dynamic named range `prioritizedNames` so my data validation looked like this:

[image: validation]

## 7. Final Result

**Lists Sheet:**

[image: lists]

**Data Sheet:**

[image: data]

Answer (score 0):

The solution of **@Engineer Toast** is very interesting, but the formulas can be shortened a bit. You can use VSTACK to combine lists, and SORTBY to reverse the order.

```
=LET(originalNames,Lists!$A$2:$A$5, chosenNames,Data!$A$2:$A$20, 
     allNames,VSTACK(originalNames,chosenNames),
     reversedNames,SORTBY(allNames,SEQUENCE(ROWS(allNames)),-1),
     uniqueNames,UNIQUE(FILTER(reversedNames,reversedNames<>0)),
     SORTBY(uniqueNames,SEQUENCE(ROWS(uniqueNames)),-1))
```

In addition, the drop-down list can be defined with a dynamic reference:

```
=Lists!$C$2#
```